# routing in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a route

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "BuildingProject",
  "BuildingProject/{action}/{id}",
  new {
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = ""
});
```

i want it to behave like default route ie for url that starts with BuildingProject like http://localhost:4030/BuildingProject/DeleteAll.
I tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "BuildingProject",
  "BuildingProject/{action}/{id}",
  new {
    controller = "Home",
    action = "",
    id = ""
});
```

It worked.But on typing localhost:4030/BuildingProject it is not redirecting to it's Index but showing error.
.How to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If your routes look like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "BuildingProject", 
        "BuildingProject/{action}/{id}", 
        new 
        { 
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
}
```

then `http://localhost:4030/BuildingProject/DeleteAll` will call the `DeleteAll` action on `Home` controller and if you navigate to `http://localhost:4030/BuildingProject`, the `Index` action will be invoked on the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 routes.MapRoute("BuildingProject", "BuildingProject/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Do you want all urls point to the same action? Then you can try this code: routes.MapRoute(null, "BuildingProject/{*catchall}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });